# Best way to compare XElement objects

Tags: .net, xml, linq, unit-testing

in a unit test I'm comparing an `XElement` object with the one I expect. The method I use is to invoke `.ToString()` on the `XElement` object and compare it with a hard-coded string value. This method turned out to be quite uncomfortable since I always have to pay attention on the formatting in the string.

I checked out the XElement.DeepEquals() method but for any reason it doesn't help.

Does anyone has an idea what is the best method I should use?

Comment: `DeepEquals` is the way to go. Please show the string representation of both XElements you are comparing.

Comment: Indeed the best way is to use DeepEqual(XElement.Parse(expectedAsString), actualXElement)!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found [this excellent article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/01/28/equality-semantics-of-linq-to-xml-trees.aspx) useful. It contains a code sample that implements an alternative to `XNode.DeepEquals` that normalises the XML trees before comparison which makes non-semantic content irrelevant.

To illustrate, the implementation of `XNode.DeepEquals` returns false for these semantically-equivalent documents:

```cs
XElement root1 = XElement.Parse("<Root a='1' b='2'><Child>1</Child></Root>");
XElement root2 = XElement.Parse("<Root b='2' a='1'><Child>1</Child></Root>");
```

However, using the implementation of `DeepEqualsWithNormalization` from the article, you'll get the value `true` because the ordering of attributes is not considered significant.  This implementation is included below.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToStringAlignAttributes(this XDocument document)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings))
            document.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static class Xsi
    {
        public static XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

        public static XName schemaLocation = xsi + "schemaLocation";
        public static XName noNamespaceSchemaLocation = xsi + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation";
    }

    public static XDocument Normalize(XDocument source, XmlSchemaSet schema)
    {
        bool havePSVI = false;
        // validate, throw errors, add PSVI information
        if (schema != null)
        {
            source.Validate(schema, null, true);
            havePSVI = true;
        }
        return new XDocument(
            source.Declaration,
            source.Nodes().Select(n =>
            {
                // Remove comments, processing instructions, and text nodes that are
                // children of XDocument.  Only white space text nodes are allowed as
                // children of a document, so we can remove all text nodes.
                if (n is XComment || n is XProcessingInstruction || n is XText)
                    return null;
                XElement e = n as XElement;
                if (e != null)
                    return NormalizeElement(e, havePSVI);
                return n;
            }
            )
        );
    }

    public static bool DeepEqualsWithNormalization(XDocument doc1, XDocument doc2,
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet)
    {
        XDocument d1 = Normalize(doc1, schemaSet);
        XDocument d2 = Normalize(doc2, schemaSet);
        return XNode.DeepEquals(d1, d2);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<XAttribute> NormalizeAttributes(XElement element,
        bool havePSVI)
    {
        return element.Attributes()
                .Where(a => !a.IsNamespaceDeclaration &&
                    a.Name != Xsi.schemaLocation &&
                    a.Name != Xsi.noNamespaceSchemaLocation)
                .OrderBy(a => a.Name.NamespaceName)
                .ThenBy(a => a.Name.LocalName)
                .Select(
                    a =>
                    {
                        if (havePSVI)
                        {
                            var dt = a.GetSchemaInfo().SchemaType.TypeCode;
                            switch (dt)
                            {
                                case XmlTypeCode.Boolean:
                                    return new XAttribute(a.Name, (bool)a);
                                case XmlTypeCode.DateTime:
                                    return new XAttribute(a.Name, (DateTime)a);
                                case XmlTypeCode.Decimal:
                                    return new XAttribute(a.Name, (decimal)a);
                                case XmlTypeCode.Double:
                                    return new XAttribute(a.Name, (double)a);
                                case XmlTypeCode.Float:
                                    return new XAttribute(a.Name, (float)a);
                                case XmlTypeCode.HexBinary:
                                case XmlTypeCode.Language:
                                    return new XAttribute(a.Name,
                                        ((string)a).ToLower());
                            }
                        }
                        return a;
                    }
                );
    }

    private static XNode NormalizeNode(XNode node, bool havePSVI)
    {
        // trim comments and processing instructions from normalized tree
        if (node is XComment || node is XProcessingInstruction)
            return null;
        XElement e = node as XElement;
        if (e != null)
            return NormalizeElement(e, havePSVI);
        // Only thing left is XCData and XText, so clone them
        return node;
    }

    private static XElement NormalizeElement(XElement element, bool havePSVI)
    {
        if (havePSVI)
        {
            var dt = element.GetSchemaInfo();
            switch (dt.SchemaType.TypeCode)
            {
                case XmlTypeCode.Boolean:
                    return new XElement(element.Name,
                        NormalizeAttributes(element, havePSVI),
                        (bool)element);
                case XmlTypeCode.DateTime:
                    return new XElement(element.Name,
                        NormalizeAttributes(element, havePSVI),
                        (DateTime)element);
                case XmlTypeCode.Decimal:
                    return new XElement(element.Name,
                        NormalizeAttributes(element, havePSVI),
                        (decimal)element);
                case XmlTypeCode.Double:
                    return new XElement(element.Name,
                        NormalizeAttributes(element, havePSVI),
                        (double)element);
                case XmlTypeCode.Float:
                    return new XElement(element.Name,
                        NormalizeAttributes(element, havePSVI),
                        (float)element);
                case XmlTypeCode.HexBinary:
                case XmlTypeCode.Language:
                    return new XElement(element.Name,
                        NormalizeAttributes(element, havePSVI),
                        ((string)element).ToLower());
                default:
                    return new XElement(element.Name,
                        NormalizeAttributes(element, havePSVI),
                        element.Nodes().Select(n => NormalizeNode(n, havePSVI))
                    );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new XElement(element.Name,
                NormalizeAttributes(element, havePSVI),
                element.Nodes().Select(n => NormalizeNode(n, havePSVI))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NB: There are some issues with `XNode.DeepEquals`.  E.g. `XNode.DeepEquals(XDocument.Parse("<a />"),XDocument.Parse("<a></a>"));` returns `false`.  See more comments on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24156847/361842

Answer (score 11):

I started down the same path as @llasarov, but also didn't like the use of strings either. I discovered XElement.DeepEquals() here, so finding the question helped *me*.

I could see that it could be difficult if your test returns a massive XML structure, but in my opinion, this should not be done - the test should check as small a structure as possible.

Say you have a method that you expect to return an element that looks like `<Test Sample="Value" />`. You can use the XElement and XAttribute constructors to build your expected value pretty easily, like this:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void MyXmlMethodTest()
{
    // Use XElement API to build expected element.
    XElement expected = new XElement("Test", new XAttribute("Sample", "Value"));

    // Call the method being tested.
    XElement actual = MyXmlMethod();

    // Assert using XNode.DeepEquals
    Assert.IsTrue(XNode.DeepEquals(expected, actual));
}
```

Even if there are a handful of elements and attributes, this is manageable and consistent.

Comment: The use of `XNode.DeepEquals` is bar far the best method I have seen or used for unit testing equality of nodes.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue comparing XElements for equality where one of the elements had child nodes that where self closing tags but the other had the open and close tags, e.g. [blah/] vs [blah][/blah]

The deep equals function was of course reporting them to be different so I needed a normalise function.  I ended up using a variant of what is posted in this blog (by "marianor"):

http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2009/01/02/easy-way-to-compare-two-xmls-for-equality.aspx

A minor change being that I use the deep equals function after normalising (rather than string compare) and also I added logic to treat elements that contain empty text the same as empty elements (to resolve the afore mentioned issue).  The result is below.

```
private bool CompareXml(string xml)
{
    var a = Normalize(currentElement);
    var b = Normalize(newElement);

    return XElement.DeepEquals(a, b);
}

private static XElement Normalize(XElement element)
{
    if (element.HasElements)
    {
        return new XElement(element.Name, element.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.Xmlns)
                                                                .OrderBy(a => a.Name.ToString()),element.Elements().OrderBy(a => a.Name.ToString())
                                                                .Select(e => Normalize(e)));
    }

    if (element.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value))
    {
        return new XElement(element.Name, element.Attributes()
            .OrderBy(a => a.Name.ToString()));
    }

    return new XElement(element.Name, element.Attributes()
        .OrderBy(a => a.Name.ToString()), element.Value);
}
```

Comment: but if the order of two elements in the file is switched this doesn't work. Suppose we want to compare file1 and file2. In file1 we have <book> <name> A</name> </book> <book><name> B</name> </book>    and in xml file2 we have <book> <name> B</name> </book> <book><name>A</name> </book>  They must be equal coz the order does not matter in xml but this function returns false.

Answer (score 3):

In xunit, you can use `Assert.Equal` with `XNode.EqualityComparer` like this:

```cs
var expected = new XElement("Sample", new XAttribute("name", "test"));
var result = systemUnderTest.DoSomething();

Assert.Equal(expected, result, XNode.EqualityComparer);
```

This method has the advantage that if the test fails, it will print out the xml elements in the error message so you can see where they differ.

Answer (score 2):

For a unit test I find the simplest approach is to just have XElement parse your expected string too.

```cs
string expected = "<some XML>";
XElement result = systemUnderTest.DoSomething();

Assert.Equal(XElement.Parse(expected).ToString(), result.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon what you're testing. Do you need to verify that the XML is equal or equivalent.

I suspect the latter in which case you should query over the xelement using xlinq and assert it has the required elements and attributes.

At the end of the day it comes down what is required. For example

```
<element att='xxxx'>
  <sub />
</element>
```

and

```
<element att='zzz' />
```

may be equivalent if you dont' care about `<sub /> or att`

Answer (score 1):

One next step that may help: a normalization that gets rid of ANY ordering. Sometimes elements order do not matter at all (think Collections rather than Lists or Arrays).

This one is based on the previous one (by RobJohnson) but also orders elements based on their "content", it uses the number of attributes, the attribute values and the Xml element value itself.

```
static XElement NormalizeWithoutAnyOrder( XElement element )
{
    if( element.HasElements )
    {
        return new XElement(
            element.Name,
            element.Attributes().OrderBy( a => a.Name.ToString() ),
            element.Elements()
                .OrderBy( a => a.Name.ToString() )
                .Select( e => NormalizeWithoutAnyOrder( e ) )
                .OrderBy( e => e.Attributes().Count() )
                .OrderBy( e => e.Attributes()
                                .Select( a => a.Value )
                                .Concatenate("\u0001") )
                .ThenBy( e => e.Value ) );
    }
    if( element.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrEmpty( element.Value ) )
    {
        return new XElement( element.Name,
                             element.Attributes()
                                    .OrderBy( a => a.Name.ToString() ) );
    }
    return new XElement( element.Name, 
                         element.Attributes()
                                .OrderBy( a => a.Name.ToString() ), 
                         element.Value );
}
```

The IEnumerable.Concatenate extension method is the same as the `string.Join` method.