# XNode.DeepEquals unexpectedly returns false

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

Using `XNode.DeepEquals()` to compare xml elements, it unexpectedly returns `false` on two xml documents that I think should be equivalent.

### Example

```
var xmlFromString = XDocument.Parse("<someXml xmlns=\"someNamespace\"/>");
var xmlDirect = new XDocument(new XElement(
  XNamespace.Get("someNamespace") + "someXml"));

Console.WriteLine(xmlFromString.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(xmlDirect.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(XNode.DeepEquals(xmlFromString, xmlDirect));
Console.WriteLine(xmlFromString.ToString() == xmlDirect.ToString());
```

### Output

```
<someXml xmlns="someNamespace" />
<someXml xmlns="someNamespace" />
False
True
```

The strings are considered equal, but the XML trees are not. Why?

Comment: Interestingly, `DeepEquals` reports false just for the root element, too... so it's not a document declaration issue, for example.

Comment: No, already tried that ;-). But if the namespace is removed it correctly reports true.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that DeepEquals() is totally not applicable for comparison. For example, it differs <node></node> and <node />. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've worked out what the difference *is*, but not *why* it's different.

In the first form, you have an `xmlns` attribute. In the second form, you don't - not in terms of what `Attributes()` returns. If you *explicitly* construct an `XAttribute`, `DeepEquals` will return `true`:

```
var xmlDirect = new XDocument(new XElement(
  XNamespace.Get("someNamespace") + "someXml",
  new XAttribute("xmlns", "someNamespace")));
```

It's as if the namespace only counts as an attribute when converting the tree to a text representation, basically.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like a bug in `DeepEquals` to me. A workaround then is to bounce the constructed xml over a string: `XNode.DeepEquals(xmlFromString, XDocument.Parse(xmlDirect.ToString())` returns true.

Comment: @AndersAbel: I can't see that it would be a bug in `DeepEquals` - it's behaving as documented, in that the two elements have different numbers of attributes. If anything, it's a bug in either parse (which perhaps shouldn't include the attribute) or `XElement` construction (which perhaps should). You've got detectably-different trees though, so it's fair for `DeepEquals` to return `false`.

Comment: You're right. `DeepEquals` isn't to blame. But `XElement.ToString()` and `XDocument.Parse` should behave consistently IMHO and either treat `xmlns` as a real attribute or not.

Answer (score 0):

After parsing you get a XDocument. Try to retrive the Node to use it in DeepEqual:

var xmlFromString = XDocument.Parse("<someXml xmlns="someNamespace"/>").**Root**;

This solved the problem for me.