# XElement changes slightly when stored in SQL Server

Tags: xml

I store an XML value into a SQL Server table column of type [XML]. When I store a value containing an empty string it will retrieve back in a different Notation:

```
<StoreMe xmlns="">
  <ImEmpty />
</StoreMe>
```

will retrieve as

```
<StoreMe xmlns="">
  <ImEmpty></ImEmpty>
</StoreMe>
```

This is causing me some problem, since the program storing the XML should compare this to some old value and XNode.DeepEqual returns false if I compare these two versions of the data.

I need some way to compare These two without dismanteling them into the original field. XNode.DeepEqual thinks they are different, is there a better way which can work out that these are the same?

Comment: [Best way to compare XElement objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318157/best-way-to-compare-xelement-objects)