# How can I compare two XElements with a different order of child elements but having the same content in LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Example:
I have:

XElement element1 =

```
<Base>
 <Node1>Value</Node1>
 <Node2>Value</Node2>
 <Node3>Value</Node3>
</Base>
```

and

XElement element2 =

```
<Base>
 <Node3>Value</Node3>
 <Node2>Value</Node2>
 <Node1>Value</Node1>
</Base>
```

By using

```
XNodeEqualityComparer equalityComparer = new XNodeEqualityComparer(); 
equalityComparer.Equals(element1 , element2 );
```

returns me false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to compare XElement objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318157/best-way-to-compare-xelement-objects)

Comment: Get the descendants of `Base` as `IEnumerable`, order it by the node name, and compare the two resulting `IEnumerable`s.

Comment: Use a left outer join by element names. Try :            var results = from e1 in element1.Element("Base").Elements()
                          join e2 in element2.Element("Base").Elements() on e1.Name.LocalName equals e2.Name.LocalName into e2a
                          from e2 in e2a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new { e1 = e1, e2 = e2};