# How to compare two xmlnodeList at the same time ? c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like to compare two xmlNodeList  and get  true only when all  the elements and inner text match otherwise false

Here is an example of my list

```
List 1
Element, Name=\"Color\"" , InnerText = While
Element, Name=\"Size\"" , InnerText = small
Element, Name=\"Year\"" , InnerText = 2019

List 2
Element, Name=\"Color\"" , InnerText = While
Element, Name=\"Size\"" , InnerText = small
Element, Name=\"Year\"" , InnerText = 2018
```

I'm currently comparing  both list  by getting each of the elements in the list
.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodeList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ComparableAttributes.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (node == Xtemp)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
     }
     return false;
```

the problem with this is that  I get true when only one of the  element match instead of all

Comment: Because you are returning from method immediately when `node == Xtemp`. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can return it when all node are equal. You have an example I can try?

Comment: [XNode.DeepEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals?view=netcore-2.1). Be sure to read the Remarks section!

Comment: [Equality Semantics of LINQ to XML Trees](http://blog.theunical.com/technology-news/equality-semantics-of-linq-to-xml-trees/). Also see [Best way to compare XElement objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7318157/5045688)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like below -

```
 var result = false;
 foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodeList)
 {
        for (int i = 0; i < ComparableAttributes.Count(); i++)
        {
            //comparison logic is incorrect. you should check the inner xml instead of node directly
            //something like node["Color"].InnerText
            if (node == Xtemp)  
            {
                result = true;
                break; //break the for loop if the result is true
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        if (!result) break; //break the main foreach if the result is false
  }
  return result;
```

You can also try `XNode.DeepEquals`

```
var xml1 = XDocument.Parse(xmldata1);
var xml2 = XDocument.Parse(xmldata2);

bool result = XNode.DeepEquals(xml1.Document, xml2.Document);
```

Comment: The `==` operator compares two `XmlNode` by reference, not by value!

Comment: very true @AlexanderPetrov. I was not focusing on comparison logic, instead I was focusing on his question